# Commands in command palette not working with several projects opened in vs code

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

I am trying to remove or add a locale or initialize it from command Palette with flutter-intl Extension. I run the command from the command palette, it just happens nothing and closes the dropdown window instantly.

I have vs code 1.51.1,

flutter Intl 1.13.0,

flutter 1.22.0, and 2 projects opened in my workspace

It is working fine with just one project opened, but not with several projects.

Answer (score 0):

i have just found where the problem was. It was in my workspace. I did not opened my projects in a workspace rather in a folder and i had also tried to put my projects in a workspace, but again i put every project in a folder inside a workspace.

i created a proper workspace and opened my projects inside and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it was due to not running the command from the command palette. No need to have or be inside Workspace for making this work. `Flutter Intl: Initialize` command should be run from command palette - the drop-down VS Code widget from top side. Keyboard shortcut for opening command palette: Ctrl + Shift + P

Answer (score 0):

For some reasons I was confused between the search bar and the command palette, which is not docked onto the  and CTRL+SHIFT+P are not exactly the same thing. For me, the former will not find any flutter command, while the later will.